# Android unable to connect to WLAN with SSID NULL

Tags: wi-fi

I was messing with my WLAN and tried setting the SSID to `NULL`. For some reason my Android Phone is unable to connect (my Laptop on the other side is able to). I know it isn't a string termination thing, as `NULL` followed by any readable character works.
Is there a reason for this or is this a bug?